# clear stack activities and finish

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

For example,

I have activity A, B, C, D

A call B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A,B.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

Then, B call C

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B,C.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

After that, C call D

```
Intent intent = new Intent(C,D.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity D, I call `finish()`. It will return back to Activity C.

My question is how can I clear Activity A, B, C before calling `finish()` so that the app quit like normal.

Don't suggest call `finish()` on every `startactivity` because the app can press back to previous activity to continue.

Comment: you mean you want to clear all activity stack before calling some activity?

Comment: check my answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570838/resuming-an-activity-without-finishing-the-others/18570914#18570914

Comment: @BirajZalavadia now the stack have activity A, B, C and D and now I call `finish()` in activity D and the app should quit instead of back to activity C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work definitely...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(D,A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("close",true);
startActivity(intent);

and in oncreat of A activity u have to write
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("close", false)) {finish();
}
else {
{
 //ur previous code here
}
```

Have fun if any problem u can ask

Comment: now the stack have activity A, B, C and D and now I call finish() in activity D and the app should quit instead of back to activity C. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is useless here

Comment: now i have edited code as ur need

Comment: I am using this "trick" too.

Comment: good keep doing well, enjoy...

Answer (score 1):

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

which ensures that if an instance is already running and is not top then anything on top of it will be cleared and it will be used, instead of starting a new instance (this useful once you've gone Activity A -> Activity B and then you want to get back to A from B, but the extra flags shouldn't affect your case above).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

So your code would be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: now the stack have activity A, B, C and D and now I call finish() in activity D and the app should quit instead of back to activity C. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` require api 11

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following in my application. Hope it will help.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // this will clear the stacks
intent.putExtra("exitme", true); // tell Activity A to exit right away
startActivity(intent);
```

and in Activity A add the following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("exitme", false)){
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seem some logic but it is not the prefect one

Comment: It does the job for me though! Using it my applications!

Answer (score 0):

try with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

see here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: now the stack have activity A, B, C and D and now I call finish() in activity D and the app should quit instead of back to activity C.

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is useless here and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` require api 11